# Where to implement textures for tiles?

Tags: java, 2d

So I just learned the basics of Java and was ready to try to create a protoype game in the style of Civ. So a tile&turn based game.

I created an enum for the different tiles:

```
public enum TerrainTile{

 WATER(1), GRASSLAND(1), HILL(2), FORREST(2), BLANK(99);

private final int id;
private final int moveCost;
private boolean hidden = true;


private TerrainTile(int moveCost) {
    this.id = this.ordinal();
    this.moveCost = moveCost;
}
```

I made a JFrame:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private MapPanel pnlMap;

public MainFrame(Terrain map) {

    setTitle("MyGame");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

    pnlMap = new MapPanel(map);
    pnlMap.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    add(pnlMap);

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            BufferedImage mapImg = null;
            try {
                mapImg = ImageIO.read(MainFrame.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("frames/resources/map2.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Terrain map = new Terrain(mapImg);
            System.out.println("Terrain created:");
            map.printTerrain();


            JFrame frame = new MainFrame(map);
            frame.setVisible(true); 

        }
```

And a JPanel for the map:

```
public class MapPanel extends JPanel {

private final Terrain map;

public MapPanel(Terrain map) {
    this.map = map;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

}
```

when I wasn't sure where to save the textures for the tiles.
Should I just read out the array of the map and do a switch statement to define inside the MapPanel class which texture to draw or should the textures better be implemented inside the enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://silveiraneto.net/2008/04/27/simple-java-tileset-example/). 
 It's common to have a single image for all your tiles and draw a different part of it at rendering. 
 You can then draw your tiles like this :

```
int mx = tileId % numberOfTileCols;
int my = tileId / numberOfTileRows;

graphics.drawImage(image, x, y,
    x + tileWidth, y + tileHeight, 
    mx * tileWidth, 
    my * tileHeight,
    mx * tileWidth + tileWidth,
    my * tileHeight + tileHeight, this);
```

This way you can store a single texture in the MapPanel but get rid of the huge switch statement.